# class member function altering class member variables after they were declared const

Tags: c++, memory, opencv, constants

Consider the following code (not exactly what I'm using but just to highlight the problem)

```
class Pointarr //creates an array of points which can be recalled by object
{
    public:
    Pointarr(int, int, bool);
    ~Pointarr(){};

    mutable Point array[];

    private:
    void fillarray(int) const;

    int const minpix;
    int const mirrors;
    bool const canvasfeed;
};

void Pointarr::fillarray(int mirrors) const
{
    Point zero(0,0);
    for(int i = 0; i < mirrors; i++)
    {
        array[i] = zero;
    }
}

Pointarr::Pointarr(Mat dt, int mpx, int mir, bool cf) : dot(dt), minpix(mpx), mirrors(mir), canvasfeed(cf)
{
    fillarray(mirrors);
}
```

I'll get some things out of the way first, i'm using the gcc c++ compiler natively on linux. I am using the OpenCV libraries in which Point is a variable type which holds coordinates in the format (x,y). I believe it simply uses enough space in the memory to hold each number so for two integers it would be 4bytes for x and 4bytes for y.

The problem I'm having is that the variables in the constructor declaration (Pointarr()) initialise properly, I confirmed this, but when I call the fillarray(int) function which fills the array with a load of zero values, (0,0), it causes the variables mirrors and minpix to both change to 0 where as canvasfeed stays as it is but this is only when mirrors is equal to 1.

Now, lets specify some things, you'll note when mirrors is 1, the loop within fill array only runs once, this means that array only has one value (one Point). If I set mirrors to 2 then canvasfeed also becomes 0. I think it is fairly clear that the fillarray function is assigning the same memory used to hold my private variables to the array and as such is changing my private variables. This is a problem because I need them to for later.

The thing is, I was lead to believe that making the private variables const means that the compiler will complain if at any point the variables are changed but it compiles fine in this case, if i'm honest though I don't completely understand how const should be used (hardly even).

So finally the question is, how do I avoid making the array use this other memory I need but still initialise it to have the same amount of element slots as mirrors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was lead to believe that making the private variables const means that the compiler will complain if at any point the variables are changed.

Either you misunderstood or your were made to believe incorrectly. There are n number of ways in which one can modify a inherently `const` member and compiler may not even be in a position to detect it. Eventually, though this leads to undefined behavior.

You are the one to ensure that directly or indirectly you never modify a inherently `const` data member.

---

```
 mutable Point array[];
```

Is known as an  Incomplete array of the type `Point`, It is guaranteed to store only a single element. When you use it for storing more elements You eventually write beyond the bounds of the array causing an **Undefined Behavior**.

You need to use an vector:

```
mutable std::vector<Point> array;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will try this and see what happens, If it's not too much trouble however, could you perhaps explain what specific difference using a vector makes (other than making it work) as i am still learning at this point. Just a link to a suitable resource would be equally appreciated.